# An addon's ToggleButton icon is not displayed when used in Tor browser

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, tor

I have a question about a strange behaviour of an addon used in Firefox (40) and Tor browser 5.0.1 (Firefox 38.2.0). The goal would be to have a working addon for both environments.

This simple example was created with `jpm init` and slightly adapted to highlight the ToggleButton problems. While the ToggleButton and its icon is displayed nicely in Firefox via `jpm run`, Tor seems to have problems finding the icon files and displays nothing. For importing the addon in Tor I've used `jpm xpi`and installed the addon via the addon-manager.

My current directory layout has the following structure:

```
├── README.md
├── data
│   ├── skull-16.png
│   ├── skull-32.png
│   ├── skull-48.png
│   └── skull-64.png
├── icon.png
├── index.js
├── package.json
└── test
    └── test-index.js
```

And this is the content of the `index.js`file:

```
const self = require('sdk/self');
const { ToggleButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/toggle");

// a dummy function, to show how tests work.
// to see how to test this function, look at test/test-index.js
function dummy(text, callback) {
    callback(text);
}

let button = ToggleButton({
    id: "skull-link",
    label: "Skull Master",
    icon: {
        "16": "./skull-16.png",
        "32": "./skull-32.png",
        "48": "./skull-48.png",
        "64": "./skull-64.png"
    },
    onChange: function() {
        console.log("toggle")
    },
    bagde: 0
});

exports.dummy = dummy;
```

Nothing special, I have just added the ToggleButton part.
I haven't found any clashes between the API in Firefox 38 and 40, so I'm clueless what might trigger this behavior. Thank you all for your help.

You can find the example in as zip-file here: [sample addon](https://unigraz-my.sharepoint.com/personal/gernot_cseh_edu_uni-graz_at/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=pYmUAcIQ4GijcvO5jYSLp1BdEJT7yivfCx2byXuHfY0%3D&docid=03d71385f0c92405c997384064d653ab9)

Comment: Hey that text version of your file structure is cool how did you do that?

Comment: If you are under Linux or OSX use the ```tree``` command. I've heard it myself for the first time approximately 5min ago :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a simple one but took me very long to figure out. I found the answer in the post [ndm13's answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/6324). If you have problems with addons working in Firefox but not Tor, append

`"permissions": {"private-browsing": true}`

to your **package.json**. Tor browser is always in private browsing mode.